# Batch delete files but keep 6 files?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory with lots of subfolders. I want to delete all files but keep the first 6 files for each subfolder. How can I batch do this on windows server 2012?

Comment: how you determine which files are 'first'? Date of creation/modification? Alphabetically?Size?

Comment: by alphabetically in ascending order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Change variables  `BaseDir` and `KeepFiles` to fit your needs.
- If the output looks ok, remove echo in the last line

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\02\SO_50129236.cmd
@Echo off & SetLocal
Set "BaseDir=Q:\Test\2018"
Set "KeepFiles=6"

Pushd "%BaseDir%" || (echo couldn't find BaseDir&Pause&exit /b 1)
For /F %%A in (
  'dir /B /S /AD 2^>nul'
) do For /F "skip=%KeepFiles% delims=" %%B in (
  'dir /B /A-D /ON "%%~fA\*" 2^>NUL'
) do Echo del "%%~fA\%%~nxB"
```

Comment: See changed version

Comment: So I tried the update version and it gives the correct path but it doesn't do any deleting at all. I tried right-clicking the bat file and run as Admin but it still doesn't delete files